# Getting error while uploading app on App Store

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload the app on the App Store but getting an error. I have tried each and every solution from the Stackoverflow but didn't find anything that can help me to solve my problem.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For issue `ERROR ITMS-90171` -> Please try deleting files from folder `Frameworks` & `Recovered References` present inside your app's folder.

For issue `ERROR ITMS-90030` -> Open the Info.plist as source code - Try removing below key-value

```
<key>NSMainNibFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
```

It worked for me.